# Add and removing a class on click in Jquery, animation not triggering

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have an animation occur on click.  It works the first time but not after that.  The animation is set up with css and works fine. My logic is to always add the class.  I thought removing and adding would help it repeat.

```
$('#animateLogo').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#animateLogo').removeClass("animated bounce");
            $('#animateLogo').addClass("animated bounce");
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside your click callback function? Try it and see if it hits the breakpoint more than once.

Comment: The click is working, it stops on every click  Here is where I got the css from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @AlexisLynneHandler, I updated my answer to include animate.css

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the other answer, the animate.css (which you're using I suppose) gives an example:

```
$("#animateLogo").click(function (e) {
    $('#animateLogo').removeClass().addClass('animated bounce').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
});
```

Source: http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: If you remove the class from the class from the button this solution will work as well

Answer (score -1):

Try class name without space and try removing space from the class name.

```js
$("#animateLogo").click(function () {
    $('#animateLogo').removeClass("animatedbounce");
    alert("continue");
    $('#animateLogo').addClass("animatedbounce");
});
```

```css
.animatedbounce {
    font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="animateLogo">Hello World!</button>
```

Fiddle here..

http://jsfiddle.net/nk609423/kuxr7ehe/

Comment: The OP is using a CSS library that requires a `bounce` class. Also, `addClass('one two three')` isnt an issue for jQuery and a very common way to add multiple classes at once